# string indices must be integers error when parsing aws sns response

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda

I have a simple lambda function in python that is being triggered by AWS SNS. This function is simply posting a response on a specific slack channel. Below is the code for that

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import urllib3
import json
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/dfsrd/B02TM68N97B/8ZjGtfMJNbcCUnUFJzn3DxI8"
    msg = {
        "channel": "#slack-mandrill",
        "username": "WEBHOOK_USERNAME",
        "text": event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'],
        "icon_emoji": ""
    }
    
    encoded_msg = json.dumps(msg).encode('utf-8')
    resp = http.request('POST',url, body=encoded_msg)
  print({
        "message": event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'], 
        "status_code": resp.status, 
        "response": resp.data
    })
```

The full response I am getting from the above lambda is like that,

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "timestamp": "2022-01-10T15:21:46.577Z",
  "requestContext": {
    "requestId": "e22f4c5c-6d32-4635-9159-ae1aadf1b4de",
    "functionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:019200159526:function:mandrill:$LATEST",
    "condition": "Success",
    "approximateInvokeCount": 1
  },
  "requestPayload": {
    **"domain": "runstraight.wombang.com"**
  },
  "responseContext": {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "executedVersion": "$LATEST"
  },
  "responsePayload": "success"
}
```

From above response I just need "domain" value and nothing else. According to JSON structure the below changes should give me the value of domain.

```
"text": event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']['domain']
```

But after this I am getting the below TypeError. Any idea how to resolve this and get only the domain value? Thanks

```
"text": event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']['requestPayload']['domain'],
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: I don't see `Records`, `Sns`, or `Message` in that full response.

Comment: Show us a complete sample of `event`.

Comment: The error message indicates that something that you think is a dictionary is actually a string. It might be a nested JSON that you need to parse with `json.loads()`

Comment: I'll bet it's `event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']`

Comment: Well I am using the below link for this function, and that all I am getting it when running this lambda. @Barmar

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-lambda-webhooks-chime-slack-teams/

Comment: That example is for Amazon Chime, but your code is using Slack.  I doubt those two formats are exactly the same.

Comment: @JohnGordon its slack there too. If you scrol down a bit thats a slack version too.

Comment: @JohnGordon check this section "Example Python code snippet for Slack" , or simply search from this one.

Comment: The error message has  `['requestPayload']['domain']` at the end that is not present in the code... What code are you actually using?

Comment: @JohnGordon, the value of domain is all I want. I mentioned what I tried.

Comment: Can you `print(event)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']` is a JSON string, not a dictionary, so you need to parse it.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/dfsrd/B02TM68N97B/8ZjGtfMJNbcCUnUFJzn3DxI8"
    msg = {
        "channel": "#slack-mandrill",
        "username": "WEBHOOK_USERNAME",
        "text": event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'],
        "icon_emoji": ""
    }
    
    encoded_msg = json.dumps(msg).encode('utf-8')
    resp = http.request('POST',url, body=encoded_msg)
    message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])
    print({
        "message": message, 
        "text": message['requestPayload']['domain'],
        "status_code": resp.status, 
        "response": resp.data
    })
```

Comment: just checked this, and this still giving me the same response that I posted in my comment.

Comment: Your original code doesn't actually have the line that gets the error, I had to guess where it belongs. Can you update the question to show the code?

Comment: nevermind, it worked. just needed to change the arrangement of some code lines. thanks @barmar